# How do I create a Windows 7 system image?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, operating-systems, mbr

I have to create a disk image of Windows 7 with all the installed applications on it, so I can restore this image later.

I am modifying my partition scheme from MBR to GUID partition table, and after changing the partition scheme, I don't want to go through the whole installation of Windows and all the apps again.

So is there any way to do this without effecting my work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the `Start Orb` and type (part of) `Backup and Restore` until you see it pop up, then go to it.

From here, click `Create a system image`, and it should guide you through creating a system image.

You can then use the Windows DVD at any time and go to recovery, then put in the disks/dvds and it should allow you to recover that image.

[image]

I wrote about this because you specifically asked about imaging. This will however undo any work you have made up until the image was taken. If you are messing around with the MBR and stuff, you may have luck simply running a `Startup Repair` from the Windows DVD, which should rebuild the boot sector and get Windows working for you.